# How to convert AxesSubplot to Axes object to make subplots_adjust works only on unconverted AxesSubplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have created two lists of `AxesSubplot`, and I only want to change the bounding box of two set of `AxesSubplot` using `subplots_adjust()` seperately. I found `subplots_adjust()` does not work on `Axes` object, which means if I convert one list of `AxesSubplot` objects to `Axes`, then `subplots_adjust()` will work fine for the rest of `AxesSubplot` objects. Pls see code below.

```py
fig, axes1 = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(7.2, 7.2))
fig.subplots_adjust(0.2, 0.2 , 0.5, 0.5) # adjust axes1
axes2 = fig.subplots(3, 3)
# only want to adjust axes2, but axes1 affected. 
# If elements in axes1 change from `AxesSubplot` to `Axes`, 
# then it will be fine, fig.subplots_adjust() only works on `AxesSubplot`.
fig.subplots_adjust(0.6, 0.6 , 0.8, 0.8)
```

I know I can get `bounds` of `AxesSubplot` and create `Axes` from that, but I am not sure if there are other ways to do it.

If there exist other ways to achieve such flexibility, pls also suggest:)

Comment: `fig2, axes2 = ...` then `fig2.subplots_adjust(0.6, 0.6 , 0.8, 0.8) `?

Comment: My code got some issues, now I changed abit, sry

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, notice in ONE figure, I generate a 2x2 and a 3x3 subplots, and I would like to adjust them individually. But `subplots_adjust ()` works for both.

Comment: What do you want to create by using `fig.subplots(3, 3)` after creating `fig` with `plt.subplots(2, 2)`?

Comment: this is just what I need in my situation, I created a 2x2 and a 3x3 and would like to place them in different positions in figure

Comment: How about `fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 5, figsize=(7.2, 7.2)) \n axs[0, 0].set_visible(False)`? Create a 5x5 figure and make some invisible.

Comment: I would like to place each of them in what ever positions with enough flexibility. What you suggested is good, but lacks flexibility of modifying the size and position of bounding box of each subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible using two different instances of [`GridSpec`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html#matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec).

Each `GridSpec` can have its own bounding `left, right, bottom, top` defined.

In this example, we create two `GridSpec`'s with different bounds, then create all the subplots for each `GridSpec` using the `.subplots` function.

Note that I coloured the faces of the subplots on the second using the `subplots_kw` option, just to make it clear which is which.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(7.2, 7.2))

gs1 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=2, ncols=2, left=0.1, right=0.6, bottom=0.55, top=0.95)
gs2 = fig.add_gridspec(nrows=3, ncols=3, left=0.4, right=0.9, bottom=0.05, top=0.45)

gs1.subplots()
gs2.subplots(subplot_kw={'facecolor': 'red'})

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: thank you so much. I solve the issue by creating `Axes` from bounds of `AxesSubplot `, and remove the original `AxesSubplot` objects. But your answer give me another solution, which is nice:)

Comment: which verison of matplotlib are u using? `gs1.subplots()` had an error reporting: 'GridSpec' object has no attribute 'subplots'. I am using 3.2.2

Comment: I'm using 3.3.0

Comment: I used `fig.add_subplot()` to get the axes already, thanks